# Stability of D-Branes and Coupling to Fields

Tags: string-theory, supersymmetry, stability, branes

I've been brushing up on my string theory using Becker, Becker, Schwarz (p. 208 in particular). They state that some D-branes can couple to R-R fields from closed string excitations.

They then go on to say that these branes are exactly 1/2 BPS and therefore stable. I understand that 1/2 BPS objects are stable because they preserve enough of the supersymmetry.

But I don't understand why the coupling to R-R fields ensures that the branes are 1/2 BPS.

Could someone possibly explain this point mathematically, and/or direct me to a reference that makes it clear?

Many thanks for your help!

**Edit**: perhaps the answer is contained within Polchinski's seminal paper [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9510017v3.pdf)? Still might be useful to get a second opinion!